# SOLID from REVOLUTION with two curve and line

Tags: animation, modifiers, extrude

Please have a look at [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxE9Rsj4140&list=TLPQMDgwOTIwMjLTeo8rVyy8Uw&index=20) My question is, how can I make the animation in the video?  Of particular interest is the selection of the region between two curves (delimited by the two parallel lines) and then extruded with rotation. Thank you in advance.

Here is a screenshot of the effect on video: [image: video screenshot]

Comment: Hello please don't right in capitals. You could do this animation with the Screw modifier for example

Comment: Thank you foryour suggetion.Anyway How to select the red region , because  only after selecting the region I can apply the Screw modifier.Please helpme to select the red region.Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to create the 4 curves (for the 4 colored lines), a mesh that is the red shape, and a second mesh that is a copy of the red shape except you don't fill the face. Give the Screw modifier to this last object

Comment: Honestly I'm not able to make this Animation , because I made 2 bezierCurve and for strait line I use 2 NurbsPath ,now I can't fid the way to intersect them i order to get the region to select .So please help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "intersect"? The red object is just a new object. For the curve animation (growing) use a bevel object and the Start and End Mapping values: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9O14_6wALk

Comment: Very nice video link. I mean How to delimit the red area once I draw the 2 cuve as in the vide you passed and 2 straight line?

Comment: My thinking is this.if you can make  insection between the straight line  with 2 curve then I get a closed are which can be selected and revolve to obtain the solid object.

Comment: You can duplicate these 4 curves and merge them with a Ctrl J, convert to mesh, then to create a vertex at each intersection enable the Auto Merge option and the Split Edges and Faces sub-option, then select, G and Enter

Comment: Honestly I don't understood clearly what you by enable the Auto Merge option and the Split Edges and Faces sub-option, then select, G. I just found how to enable auto merge option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've created your 4 curves, duplicate them, join the duplications with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, right click > *Convert to > Mesh*:

[image]

In the *Options* panel enable the *Auto Merge* option and *Split Edges & Faces* (if you don't find this panel open the *N panel > Tool > Options*):

[image]

Now press <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> right away, it creates 4 vertices at the intersections of the edges:

[image]

Remove the useless vertices:

[image]

Duplicate the mesh, fill one version, use the other version to create the revolution effect with the *Screw* modifier (make sure to place the origin of the object at the center of the rotation, keyframe the *Angle* value to animate:

[image]

For the growing effect of your 4 initial curves, use the *Bevel* and the *Start & End Mapping* values as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9O14_6wALk).